# Fibonacci Random Number number generator returning negative numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've tried to implement a Subtractive Lagged Fibonacci Random Number Generator using the following formula: 
 = ([−] − [−])

But sometimes it is generating negative numbers. After searching a few days the internet I could not find any answer or a bug in my code. Could any of you help me understand what am I doing wrong?

```
class LaggedFibonaci_RNG : IRandomNUmberGenerator
{
    private double[] initArray = null;
    private int j = 1029;
    private int k = 2281;
    private int n = 0;
    private double m = Math.Pow(2, 32);
    private double Xn = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public LaggedFibonaci_RNG()
    {
        n = k;
        initArray = new double[n];
        // create initial array 
        for (int i = 0; i < initArray.Length; i++)
        {
            initArray[i] = rand.Next();
        }
    }


    public double GenerateNextRandomNumber()
    {
        double randomNumber = 0;
        //decrement j or set to optimal
        if (j <= 1)
        {
            j = 1029;
        }
        else
        {
            j--;
        }
        // decrement k or set to optimal
        if (k <= 1)
        {
            k = 2281;
        }
        else
        {
            k--;
        }

        ////  apply the fibonacci formula
        //randomNumber = (Xn * (n - j) - Xn * (n - k)) % m;

        //// update the initial array at position n - k to hold the random number generated
        //initArray[n - k] = randomNumber;
        //Xn = randomNumber;

        double firstElement = initArray[n - j];
        double secondElement = initArray[n - k];

        randomNumber = (firstElement - secondElement) % m;
        initArray[n - k] = randomNumber;

        //return the generated number
        return randomNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes sense that negative numbers can occur here, since it is not said that `X[n-f]` is always greater than `X[n-k]`. You need a `mod` instead of a `rem`, I think, so `(((X[n-f] - X[n-k])%m)+m)%m`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the one that you are implying is a Multiplicative generator, I need to do a Subtractive thats why the -.  But, I read a lot of articles and I could not find if indeed the subtractive one should return also negative numbers.

Comment: Why initialize `n` to `0` if it just gets reassigned it in the constructor?

Comment: `randomNumber = (firstElement - secondElement) % m;` You aren't doing any validation that `firstElement` is larger than `secondElement`. If you don't want negative numbers, then you could just get the absolute value: `randomNumber = Math.Abs(firstElement - secondElement) % m;`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am sorry but I do not follow you , why do %m)+m)%m when the function is Xn=(X(n-j)-X(n-k) ) mod m

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez: well `mod` and `rem` are confusing. `mod` usually takes the sign of the *divisor*, not the *dividend*. C#'s `%` is a *remainder* operation, not a modulo.

Comment: Methinks the trick is to add m, so (m + x[a]  - X[b]) mod m. In essence this is nothing different then taking (x[a] + x[b]) mod m because we assume that x[a] and x[b] are random. True randomness is of course never observed with these pseudo-random number generation processes.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje: no, it is not, `m-X[b]` is not the same as `m+x[b]`, note that you should *not* add `m` inside the addition by the way, but *after* we did the first remainder operation.

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez `((X[n-f] - X[n-k]) % m + m) % m` will return the same thing as your code if `X[n-f] - X[n-k]` is positive, but if it's negative, then it will return `m` plus the negative result. To give an example: `((5 - 6) % 7 + 7) % 7 = 6` and `((6 - 5) % 7 + 7) % 7 = 1`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in any case it's silly to define this as a subtraction of two previously generated values. It gets you into areas of obfuscation that is not needed at all. It's been a long time that I studied RNGs but this subtraction thing does not make sense at all.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje: well I was suprised myself, but on the wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagged_Fibonacci_generator), it says "*The ⋆ operator denotes a general binary operation. This may be either addition, **subtraction**, multiplication, or the bitwise arithmetic exclusive-or operator (XOR)*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [Wikipedia article on the modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) shows that there is no complete agreement on how modulo and remainder are defined. It is however more common for a *modulo* operation to take the sign of a *divisor*, whereas the *remainder* frequently takes the value of the *dividend*. See for example [this math answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519853/26494):

> To find *−b* mod *N*, just keep adding *N* to *-b* until the **number is between *0* and *N***.

So *-5 mod 3* is *1*, whereas *-5 rem 3* is *-2*.

With that definition in mind, C#'s [**`%` operator** [language reference]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-), is a *remainder* operator, *not* a *modulo* operator.

Given that `m` is a *positive* number, we can however make use of the remainder to calculate a modulo operation. For a positive *m*:

*a* mod *m = ((a* rem *m)+m)* rem *m*

We can thus use that in our formula here, and write it like:

```
randomNumber = (((firstElement - secondElement) % m) + m) % m;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. This solved my problem.